# Minutes and Seconds between 2 Datetimes

Tags: javascript

How can I get minutes and seconds in format -> mm:ss

```
// What I tried
var cur_time = new Date();
var round_end_on = new Date(Date.parse(round_time,"Y-m-d H:I:s"));

var diff = round_end_on - cur_time;
var remaining_minutes = diff / 1000 / 60;
var remaining_seconds = ???;
```

`remaining_minutes` seems to work, but I don't know how to get the remaining seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var remaining_seconds = diff / 1000;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this will return values greater than 60. Which is usually not wanted in a `mm:ss` format (`23:84` looks kinda odd).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following.

```
(diff/1000) % 60
```

Answer (score 0):

`var remainingSeconds = Math.floor(differenceInMsec / 1000 % 60);`

Will give you the remaining seconds (0-60) as integer.

`var remainingMinutes = Math.floor(differenceInMsec / 1000 / 60);`

Will give you the remaining minutes (0-...) as integer.

Both values are rounded down, because 'half-minutes' would be displayed in seconds, and 'half-seconds' would be displayed by miliseconds.